# Computing expected value of sum of two random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value

Let $X$ denote the outcome of a standard six-sided dice. Let $Y$ denote the outcome of a standard six-sided dice, but we only roll $Y$ provided that $X \geq 3$. If $X \leq 2$, then set $Y = 0$. Compute $E(X + Y)$ and $\text{Var}(X + Y)$.

---

So I computed $E(X)$ as follows: $E(X) = \frac{2}{6}(1.5) + \frac{4}{6}(4.5) = 1.5$.

Also $E(Y) = \frac{2}{6}(0) + \frac{4}{6}(3.5) = 2.333$.

Then I summed to get $3.83$ for $E(X + Y)$ but this is wrong.

Can someone help explain why?

Comment: What happens if $X = 2$?

Comment: Check my edit please

Comment: Consider $E(Z)=\sum_iE(Z\mid X=i)P(X=i).$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your $E(X)$ is calculated incorrectly. $X$ is just a single die roll, which should have expected value $3.5$. Period. It doesn't matter that we change the rules for the next roll based on the value of $X$ - $X$ itself is still just a single fair die roll.

Now, looking closer at that - you have a correct formula for $E(X)$. You just didn't evaluate it properly.

Your $E(Y)$ is correct, and the expected values do sum.

Comment: so I got $5.8333$ as the sum but I still think it's wrong. i listed out all $26$ cases and got a different answer

Comment: That is the correct expected value for the sum. Have you accounted for the fact that your $26$ cases aren't equally probable? (The case "Roll a 1, don't roll the second die" is six times as probable as "Roll a 5, then roll a 5", for example)

Comment: i understand, thanks